# Como criar umaTrigger After Update

Tags: mysql, trigger

Preciso criar uma Trigger que execute um update na coluna A da tabela T, assim que a coluna B dessa tabela seja atualizada.
Então acredito que eu precise criar um After Update.
Mas pelo que eu entendi, não é possivel.
Ao tentar fazer isso, o seguinte erro ocorre:

```
16:03:54    UPDATE esms_conta SET valor_sms=0.3 WHERE id= 127   Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'esms_conta' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.    0.000 sec
```

Segue a minha trigger

```
DELIMITER ;;
    CREATE TRIGGER `e-sms-db`.`esms_conta_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `esms_conta`
     FOR EACH ROW
     BEGIN
         UPDATE esms_conta SET sms_disponivel = 10 WHERE id = NEW.id;
     END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode mexer nos dados da própria tabela que ativou o gatilho *(trigger).* A solução é criar uma *trigger before update:*

```
DELIMITER ;;
CREATE TRIGGER `e-sms-db`.`esms_conta_b_u` BEFORE UPDATE ON `esms_conta`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.sms_disponivel = 10;
END ;;
DELIMITER ;
```